# Images of the fundamental domain of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\backslash \mathbb{H}$ whose Euclidean area is large

Tags: modular-forms, modular-group, conferences

Let $S$ be a compact subset of the closure of the upper half plane. (Assume that $S$ is a (Euclidean) rectangular box, if you wish.) Let $D$ be the standard fundamental domain of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\backslash \mathbb{H}$. What is a simple way to construct all maps $g\in \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that the Euclidean area of $g D\cap S$ is at least $\epsilon$? Is there a (good) a priori bound for the size of the entries of a matrix $g$ satisfying such a property?

(Yes, my question *is* motivated by the need to produce a good conference poster, but I hope that will make it more rather than less interesting.)

Comment: It depends on what the hyperbolic area of $S$ is.

Comment: In the case of a box $\lbrack 0,N\rbrack \times \lbrack 0,N\rbrack$ (a good example, actually), the hyperbolic area of $S$ is $\infty$, yet the question still makes sense. So, you really have to know what $S$ is. (And as I said, you may assume it is a box.)

Comment: It's not exactly an answer to your question, but isn't the easiest thing just to compute the ball of a certain radius $d$ in the Cayley graph?  This would be very easy to programme. Because of the amalgamated free product decomposition of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, there will be no redundancy if you choose the right generating set.

Comment: @HJRW Well, the Cayley graph is not quasi-isometric to $\mathbb{H}^2,$ so this is a little problematic.

Comment: @IgorRivin - I mean that it's easy to list all the elements in a certain ball in the Cayley graph, and you can then use the corresponding matrices to compute the translates of the fundamental domain.  Quasi-isometry doesn't come into it.

Comment: @HJRW But how does that answer Harold's question?

Comment: @Igor, it's just how I'd make a nice poster. I said it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: By the way, Harold->Harald above. Damn you, autocorrect!

Comment: HJRW - this (= going over a ball in the Cayley graph) is actually how I am producing drafts of posters right now. I still think it would be nice to know a priori how far one needs to go.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here is a simple way to construct maps, which might work well: sample points in your domain randomly, so that the area of the Voronoi region is of order of $\epsilon$ (sampling something like $2 A(S)/\epsilon$ points should work.) Then use the ``extended'' continued fraction algorithm (which gives the transformation matrices), as described in my paper ["How to pick an random integer matrix".](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.4607) The set of all matrices you get should be more or less what you want.

Comment: This is a good idea, but I'd still like to have an explicit bound. $2 A(S)/\epsilon$ (where $A(S)$ is presumably the Euclidean area of $S$) can be pretty large.

Comment: @HAHelfgott In your special example, this is clearly too large, since the standard parabolic will eat up most of your domain. However, if your rectangle crawls along the real axis, I don't know that you can do better than $c A(S)/\epsilon.$

Comment: Well, one can take care of the region $\Re(y)>1$ in the obvious way, and then apply a Monte Carlo method like this one to the rest. Still, this isn't really that satisfying.

Answer (score 2):

This turns out to be an easy problem. For any $\epsilon>0$, we can cover all of $\mathbb{H}$ except for a domain U of area $\epsilon$ and its (horizontal) translates by $\mathbb{Z}$ using words on $S = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & -1\\
1 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$ and $T = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right)$ that involve at most $\ll \log(1/\epsilon)$ appearances of the involution $S$ (which corresponds to the map $w:z\mapsto -1/z$), and at most $\ll 1/\epsilon$ appearances of $T$ (which corresponds to the map $z\mapsto z+1$).

This is

(a) essentially optimal: $(D+n)^{-1}$ (where $D$ is the fundamental domain) has Euclidean area $\gg 1/n^2$, and $ST^{-1}ST...ST^{-1}ST(D)$ ($(\log \epsilon)$ repetitions) isn't that small either;

(b) good enough in practice, if, say, we are producing a poster: powers of $T$ come for free, whereas each appearance of $S$ corresponds to one more step in the continued fraction algorithm (the obvious one; I just checked that it's the same as the one in page 7 of the paper Igor R. kindly linked to in the above).

Sketch of proof. Write $V$ for the closure of the standard fundamental domain $D$. The union of $V+\mathbb{Z}$, $V^{-1}+\mathbb{Z}$ and $(V+1)^{-1}+\mathbb{Z}$ covers all of $\mathbb{H}$ except for a set contained in $\{x+i y: 0< y < 1/(2\sqrt{3})\}$. Let us look at the intersection of that set with $\{x+i y: |x|\leq 1/2\}$. All of its elements $z$ satisfy $|z|\leq 1/3$. Hence, in a neighbourhood of $w^{-1}(z) = -z^{-1}$, the map $w$ shrinks
everything by a factor of at least $3-\epsilon$. Now repeat.

(As for the map $z\mapsto z+1$: the map $w$ shrinks anything in $\{x + i y: y>0, n+1/2\leq x\leq n+3/2\}$ by a factor $\ll 1/n$.)